# Could not read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have developed android application using sqlite database. but i got the error and i was unable to fix that.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure     the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

This is my code

```
try {

            db = openOrCreateDatabase("book_category_db1",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_details1(book_name VARCHAR,author_name VARCHAR,description VARCHAR,state VARCHAR,category VARCHAR);");
            c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM book_details1", null);


             if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                    String book_name =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("book_name"));
                    String author_name = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("auther_name"));
                    String state = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("state"));

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();            


                    map.put(TAG_BOOK_NAME, book_name);
                    map.put(TAG_AUTHER_NAME, author_name);
                    map.put(TAG_STATE, state);
                    contactList.add(map);


                    } while (c1.moveToNext());

             }


            db.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your book list is emplty."+ e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
            db.close();


        }
```

Can some one please help me to solve this problem. I try and try but couldn't find the solution for this. I'm using Android sqlire raw query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the column name here:

```
String author_name = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("auther_name"));
```

should be

```
String author_name = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("author_name"));
```

(Note: "auth **o** r_name", not "auth **e** r_name")

Since `auther_name` is not a valid column name, `getColumnIndex` returns `-1`, which leads you to the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Thnx :D. I didn't see that :(

Comment: It might be a good idea to use contract classes for column names to avoid this, especially if you're using the same column names over and over.

Comment: @samuelowino, then it's not the same error. Sounds like you're reading your table past the end.

Comment: Actually you are right, I overlooked the resultset iteration after moveToFirst () call.